# What are the best macro lenses for canon ef mount?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, macro, macro-lenses

Taking into consideration price, what are the best macro lenses for not-to-serious photography? Price is a big factor for me.

And I know it is a subjective question. I do not mind subjective answers.

Comment: The most cost effective solution is to adapt a non-macro lens, see http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9341/what-macro-techniques-offer-an-alternative-to-expensive-optics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best would be to adapt a non macro lens, There are many ways to do this, lens reversal, extension tubes, etc... if you want to buy a macro lens, for a $500 price tag you can get the older 100mm f/2.8 you can read a [review here](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Canon-EF-100mm-f-2.8-USM-Macro-Lens-Review.aspx), also for about the same price you can get the [Sigma 70mm f/2.8](http://www.photozone.de/Reviews/300-sigma-af-70mm-f28-ex-dg-macro-canon-review--test-report), however, I would go with the Canon.