# Is Canon MP-E 65mm f/2.8 1-5X macro lens good for photos other than close-up macro shots?

Tags: lens, macro, macro-lenses, canon-mp-e-65mm

Does this lens do a good job for photos other than close-up macro shots?  For example, does it make sense to use this lens for outdoor family portrait photography? What are some other common uses for this lens?

Answer (score 9):

No. The MP-E is a dedicated macro-only lens. The farthest away it can focus is just far enough to get a 1:1 macro shot. It can **only** take shots between life-size and five times life-size. The only way you'd be able to take a picture from further away is to adapt the lens to a mirrorless body, and it's not a sure thing that you'd be ablt to focus at infinity even at that.

Comment: Re: mirrorless body - Because of the shorter flange distance?

Comment: @MichaelClark - exactly. At 1:1, the optical centre of the lens (the point where an equivalent thin single lens would be) is twice as far from the image plane as it would be at infinity focus. Since that is the closest that the MP-E can focus on its standard mount, the solution to more distant focus would be to bring the optical centre closer to the sensor.