# Using a Sony E mount lens on a Nikon body?

Tags: lens, nikon, sony, lens-adapter

I was just wondering if it's possible to use a Sony E mount lens on the Nikon D3200 by using an adaptor? I recently got given a Sony lens for free so I dont want to get rid of it.

Comment: There is more to it than just _attaching_ the lens. Sony E-mount uses a shorter "[registration distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flange_focal_distance)" than Nikon F-mount cameras, so it won't work without adding (image-degrading) lens elements.

Comment: The reasons are described by others, but they don't make clear - There is no adapter to use an E-mount lens normally on any other camera body.  Such an adapter will likely never be commercially manufactured.

Comment: For a different use case, you could use the lens for macro photography with a lens reversal adapter.  See [What macro techniques offer an alternative to expensive optics?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/13536/75526)

Answer (score 0):

This would only at all work with a *manually controllable* E mount lens (IIRC none of Sony's own lenses are) that is to be used as a *macro only* lens. You would have to literally sink the lens inch deep into the mirrorbox of a Nikon DSLR to be able to focus it to infinity.

If you do not want to sell the lens ... get a simple E mount body (some of the APS-C ones are not expensive secondhand, eg NEX-6) and use it. BTW, adapting Nikon lenses as manual focus lenses to E-mount cameras is almost trivial unless they are AF-P.